# Hausdorff and Minkowski dimension exercises.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, harmonic-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

I  started reading the book my professor gave me to start  my p.h.d.

My thesis will be in Harmonic Analysis and Geometric measure theory and especially Kakeya type problems and Kakeya maximal functions combined with Hausdorff and Minkowski dimension.

> But since its the beginning and the book he proposed me has not exercises, i would like if someone who is an expert in these fields(or in general who knows) can provide me a collection of exercises about Hausdorff dimension and Minkowski dimension( for instance computing dimensions of sets,exercises about properties of those notions and their connections and everything that will help me to practice and get comfortable with these notions).

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some published references are in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/796073/13130), along with these two items: Mark Pollicott, [**Lectures on Fractals and Dimension Theory**](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masdbl/dimension-total.pdf) (2005) *AND* David Worth, [**Construction of Geometric Outer-Measures and Dimension Theory**](https://math.unm.edu/~loring/graduate_students/DaveWorthThesis.pdf), 2006 MS Thesis. I also have a .pdf of an MA thesis with several simple examples worked in detail --- [send me an email](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13130/dave-l-renfro?tab=profile).

Comment: It's Dave.Renfro (capitals not needed), and I got the email, and I just sent you the thesis along with a comment about 5 of the better known fractal dimensions and how they compare with each other (as described [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/273234/15780)).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro..Yes i got the message. Thank you.